# .net 6 Blazor Server app - Not working after deployment

Tags: blazor-server-side, iis-8, windows-server-2019

This is driving me crazy , I have an app that works local but when deployed to windows server  2019 I get the error that say

[image]

and when I inspect the browser console I get this

[image]

I get no errors in the windows event logs , I have installed .net 6 hosting bundle, when run the console app alone it does not have any errors.

Has anyone came across this?

Comment: You should try run it with IIS Express first, the behavior should be same as  IIS in windows server. Make sure your publish files have no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up being an access issue. For whatever reason the exception was not being logged, and since the response was coming back as HTML it explains the "unexpected token" error in the browser console.

So far , I really love blazor , but debugging is a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it in my local and can't reproduce the issue. But you can follow my suggestions to troubleshoot.

[image]

**Suggestions**

1. You also need install .net core runtime at the beginning. For more details, you can read [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/).
2. Please make sure you can run your project with IIS Express model successfully, like below

   [image]
3. After the steps you have tried, if you still facing some issue, please try to re-publish the project, make sure the content is latest.
4. You can enable `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` to check the logs.
5. If you have free trial in azure, you can try to deploy it, and if it can run normally, that mean your server has some issue or wrong settings.

Comment: Tried all that, stdout shows nothing out of the ordinary. IIS Express runs like a champ on my local machine, funny thing is error page I am getting is served by the application. So far what I have gathered is when the app is trying to request blazor.server.js its probably getting a HTML back which is causing the error - I cant see what the underlying error is and no log has helped yet. But I think you are correct this more then likely is a server set up problem - I do have other sites that work on that same box though. I will keep on digging

Answer (score 0):

*I was having a problem with this topic as well. You may also have the following situation as a similar issue.*

It turned out that the problem was nothing to do with my code, nor my site settings on the server. I use **Cloudflare**, and had set it to minify HTML. This removes the two HTML comments that are essential for Blazor to work. See this article for more information.

So, if you are using Cloudflare, by all means set it to minify JavaScript and CSS, but DO not minify HTML.

[image]

Comment: https://zimmergren.net/solved-asp-net-core-blazor-web-sites-does-not-work-with-cloudflare-html-minification/